# Convert Unicode data to int in python

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, casting

I am getting values passed from url as :

```
user_data = {}
if (request.args.get('title')) :
    user_data['title'] =request.args.get('title')
if(request.args.get('limit')) :
    user_data['limit'] =    request.args.get('limit')
```

Then using it as

```
if 'limit' in user_data :
    limit = user_data['limit']
conditions['id'] = {'id':1}
int(limit)
print type(limit)
data = db.entry.find(conditions).limit(limit)
```

It prints : `<type 'unicode'>`

but i keep getting the `type` of `limit` as `unicode`, which raises an error from query!! I am  converting unicode to int but why is it not converting??
Please help!!!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`int(limit)` returns the value converted into an integer, and doesn't change it in place as you call the function (which is what you are expecting it to).

Do this instead:

```
limit = int(limit)
```

Or when definiting `limit`:

```
if 'limit' in user_data :
    limit = int(user_data['limit'])
```

Comment: +1 And by `doesn't change it immediately` meaning it doesn't change it by reference.

Comment: @Jared I'll add this, thanks :). I knew my wording wasn't perfect in some way :p

Comment: @MANCHUCK Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 7):

In python, integers and strings are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python) and are [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). You cannot pass a string, or integer, to a function and expect the argument to be modified.

So to convert string `limit="100"` to a number, you need to do

```
limit = int(limit) # will return new object (integer) and assign to "limit"
```

If you *really* want to go around it, you can use a list. Lists are mutable in python; when you pass a list, you pass it's reference, not copy. So you could do:

```
def int_in_place(mutable):
    mutable[0] = int(mutable[0])

mutable = ["1000"]
int_in_place(mutable)
# now mutable is a list with a single integer
```

But you should not need it really. (maybe sometimes when you work with recursions and need to pass some mutable state).